# Resizable background-image in css body but avoid repeating

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to add this image https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/Coffee_and_Friends_(Unsplash).jpg/2560px-Coffee_and_Friends_(Unsplash).jpg  as background-image for body selector.

Here's my code

```
body {
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/Coffee_and_Friends_%28Unsplash%29.jpg/2560px-Coffee_and_Friends_%28Unsplash%29.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

it's working fine but at certain size image started to repeat so I added
**background-repeat: no-repeat;** in code.

Now in place of repeated image there is white space in window, **How to fill this white space with single image ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `background-position` and `background-attachment` properties:

- background-position will set the starting position of your background image
- background-attachment (set to fixed) will prevent your background image from scrolling with the content of your page

```css
body {
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/Coffee_and_Friends_%28Unsplash%29.jpg/2560px-Coffee_and_Friends_%28Unsplash%29.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}

p {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>
    Some text
  </p>
</body>
```